# What is the selected application for XFCE's exo-open?

Tags: xfce, file-opening

Under XFCE, `xdg-open` calls `exo-open`.

When `exo-open` is called with `--launch` is uses the application set with `xfce4-settings-manager`.

However, when one calls `exo-open foo.txt` (local path, without `--launch`), how is the corresponding application selected?

Answer (score 0):

It uses a mime database. You can use the Mime Type Editor in Xfce to change the user-specific default applications (`xfce4-mime-settings`).